# How do I decide that a sequence is convergent in a metric space? Following example below.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces

Is the following sequence convergent in [image]?(Metric space is the normal, euclidean space)
[image]

Comment: The second coordinate might look more familiar if you make the substitution $u=\cot^2\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I know that the limes of the first coordinate is 1, and the second is now e, but is it convergent in this metric space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first coordinate, L'Hopital's rule shows that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{1}=0.$$

In the second coordinate, make the substitution $u=\cot^2\frac{1}{n}$ to obtain
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\tan^2\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\cot^2\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{u}\right)^u=e.$$

Now as per your question, why can we conclude that if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n \to y$ we also have $(x_n,y_n)\to(x,y)$? Just note that in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$\|(x_n,y_n)-(x,y)\|^2=|x_n-x|^2+|y_n-y|^2\to 0$$
as $n\to\infty$.

So this sequence does converge to $(0,e)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\frac{\ln n}{n}$ apply L'Hôpital. For the second part use

$$
e^{\cot^2 (\frac{1}{n})\ln(1+tan^2\frac{1}{n})}=(1+tan^2\frac{1}{n})^{\cot^2 (\frac{1}{n})}
$$

Also note that $e$ is continuous. This gives you the limit as $(0,e)$